# Cucumber did not create a folder, instead created a file

Tags: directory, cucumber

I have tried to create a folder named `HtmlReports` under using cucumber pretty. When I ran the Runner Class it has created a `HtmlReports` file instead of creating a folder.

**This is my Code.**

```
package Stepdefinition;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/Features",
monochrome = true,
plugin={"pretty","html:target/HtmlReports"}
)
public class Testrunner {

    
}
```

[image: This is the Screenshot of the file created]

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Cucumber v6 the html formatter was improved somewhat. It [now outputs a single page html report](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v6.0.0.md#improved-html-formatter). You can open it by adding the `.html` extension.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "html:target/cucumber-report.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a folder instead of a file.
For maven project - "cucumber-java & cucumber-JUnit" dependencies version should below v6 or 5.7.0 (i had used for my project)